# Where to load dynamic user controls?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, webforms

I am trying to load a user control from a content page, but it loads twice... I've read this is due to the AutoEvent attribute set to true. Unfortunately, the page doesn't work with this setting off, so is there a different method I can load the control in that won't get fired twice?

Comment: Going to be difficult to work out if we don't have something to look at. Please *edit* your question with example code

Comment: This can happen if you have an error in your html markup (either what you wrote, or what .Net generates). Have you tried checking for errors with Chrome Developer Tools? I think that is a good place to start.

Comment: For some reason my button was styled to look like textbox (including width)...

Comment: Check for its existence.  If exists, don't add, else add.  Would be helpful to see some bit of code though.